# Fastest way of checking for word in huge list of keywords - Python performance

Tags: python, performance, search

*Thanks for amazingly quick response. Stackoverflow is awesome!*

I need to check if a word (or rather thousands of them) is matching a dict containing keywords.

For example, say I have a string: `"The fluffy fox jumped the friggin fence."`  I need to check each word of the string against a dict of keywords, and if there's a match, return all values.

I've created a dict `filters`: (`uniqueid` means ie. "lk2m3lk4m2", rest is 'static'.)

```
filters:
        { "fox" : [
                    { 'subscription' : 'uniqueid', 'link' : 'uniqueid' },
                    { 'subscription' : 'uniqueid', 'link' : 'uniqueid' }
                  ]},

        { "fence" : [
                      { 'subscription' : 'uniqueid', 'link' : 'uniqueid' }
                    ]}
```

...and plan to iterate over filters for each word in string (and I have to do this with perhaps 5000 words / second.  In other words, performance is the issue ABOVE ALL.

The number of filter-keywords may grow to thousands, while the strings will never be more than a normal sentence long (ie. 5-20 words). I'll therefore iterate over each word in the string and check if it's contained in the filter-list.  However, at 500 sentences / second, I'm still looking at a lot of computation.

Is it possible to sort the list (ie. the key of dict's in list) and thus drastically improve performance, for example?  And are there C-implementations I should use (like I'm using cjson with great performance gain)?

Sorry for the somewhat fluid question -- but how should I go about this task?

Edit:

Expected input:
 `"The fluffy fox jumped the friggin fence."`

Expected output: 
`{ 'subscription' : 'flskdmfslk32232', 'link' : 'sfdksmfls22323' },
                    { 'subscription' : '3023940fsdf', 'link' : 'sdflsfm223' }`  
(ie. the subscriptions listed under each matching keyword.)

Comment: Can you give some example input and expected output?

Comment: If each possible word is unique (i.e., if there can be no overlap between "fox", "fence", etc. in your dict), then why are you using a list of dicts instead of one big dict?  Using one big dict would let you leverage the existing efficiency of dict lookup, and would remove the need to sort it.

Comment: Dictionaries are implemented with a hash table and should be about as fast as you can get.

Comment: Why are you storing multiple dictionaries in one list instead of just using one dictionary? If the order is important, you might want to use [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead. Using a dictionary would most likely speed up your algorithm by a very large margin.

Comment: Yes, each entry ("fox") is unique. I made a list because I figured it could be sorted and thus speed things up. You're saying dict with unique values is faster. Thanks!

Comment: Access to a `dict` is O(1), so even if you do binary search in that list you'll still have much worse performance.

Comment: Bakuriu: That's great. Thank you. And for checking eg. 5000 words against dict of 1000 keys per second, this is the most efficient way - simply checking if key exist?

Comment: BTW, 5000 dict lookups per second is trivially achievable. Try it yourself. I ran `a = {x:x for x in range(10000000)}` to make a dict with 10,000,000 items. Then I ran `for x in range(1000000): a[x]` to do 1,000,000 key lookups. That loop finished before my finger had released the enter key.

Comment: @KirkStrauser not that I know anything about Python, so please correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't a string lookup be significantly slower than the integer based example you provided due to the more-complex hash function?

Comment: but I agree 5000 is not an overly difficult goal

Comment: @AK4749 No, not really. In either case, it's generating a hash value of the input and using that to perform the O(1) lookup. Even if it were 200 times slower, it'd still run much faster than 5,000 lookups per second. For a real-world number, I have a program that does about 600,000 lookups per second using 15-element long tuples as keys.

Comment: @KirkStrauser gotcha, makes sense on the lookup speed being more than sufficient. I was curious about the relative hashing performance, thanks

Comment: If you really care about performance, stop asking people to guess what's going to be fastest, and actually test. Sometimes you will want to analyze the code _on top of_ testing, but you'll almost never want that _instead of_ testing. See the `timeit` module for help.

Comment: @abamert: Great advice, thank you. I sure will start using `timeit`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can determine if a word is a key in filters by simply by doing filters.has_key(word) or by doing:

```
subscriptions = filters.get(word)
if subscriptions is not None:
    pass # TODO do something with subscriptions
```

or:

```
try:
    subscriptions = filters[word]
    # TODO do something with subscriptions
except:
    pass # probably don't need to do anything if not present
```

It isn't necessary to iterate over each entry in filters.  Rather you will want to split your input string, add each word to a Set (to eliminate duplicates), and then iterate over your set to look up each word in your filters dictionary.

Comment: Thanks! And for performance, which is faster (less CPU use)? I'm doing 5-10k words per second towards 1000 keywords.

Comment: I agree with the approach, but `filters.has_key(word)` has been spelled like `word in filters` for a while now. :-)

Comment: Which one will be faster will depend on your filters and input data.  try/except is generally considered cheaper than a branch (if) when no exception is thrown; however, it is slower to catch a raised exception than do a branch.  Thus it will depend on how many exception are thrown.  Since there are only 1000 keywords, I suggest going with the version using get and the branch rather than using the try/except version as it seems likely a lot of words will not be present in filters.

Comment: OK. Thanks everyone for great help!

Comment: Sorry to continue, but what's the most efficient way of searching for each word in sentence? If I do `for word in sentence: if word in filter: print filter[word]` for example, word is each letter in sentence, not each word? Is `.split(' ')` efficient? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, split will almost certainly be much faster than you need it to be. I created a string with `a = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'`, then ran `for i in range(100000): _ = a.split()`. Again, the 100,000 loops were faster than my ability to release the enter key. :-)

Comment: @Knut Ole: A word of caution regarding the second block of code suggested: Avoid bare `except:` clauses especially after `try`s covering multiple non-trivial statements since it can be a very misleading and make things difficult to debug.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to do it in Python would be to use a dictionary look each word of the sentence up in it, and accumulate and associated values. The main data structure would probably look something like this:

```
filters = {
    "fox" : (
              ('uniqueid1', 'uniqueid2'),
              ('uniqueid3', 'uniqueid4'),
            ),
    "fence" : (
                ('uniqueid5', 'uniqueid6'),
              ),
          }
```

Using this way (on 8-bit chars):

```
from string import punctuation

sentence = 'The fluffy fox jumped the friggin fence.'
sentence = sentence.translate(None, punctuation)  # remove punctuation chars

print [filters.get(word) for word in sentence.split() if word in filters]
```

Or it might be faster (time it to find out) like this which avoids a double dictionary look-up:

```
from string import punctuation

def map_words(sentence):
    for word in sentence.translate(None, punctuation).split():
        try:
            yield filters[word]
        except KeyError:
            pass

sentence = 'The fluffy fox jumped the friggin fence.'
print [v for v in map_words(sentence)]
```

Either way this is the output:

```
[(('uniqueid1', 'uniqueid2'), ('uniqueid3', 'uniqueid4')), (('uniqueid5', 'uniqueid6'),)]
```

Comment: Thank you. Is this the bleeding edge performance wise as well?

Comment: It depends on if your data in each filter entry is fixed (i.e. it's always just a pair of ids) or if it's variable (i.e. sometimes it has a timestamp, a comment, and/or a moderator flag).  If it is fixed then using tuples as shown here will be faster.  Here the tuples containing the id pairs are contained in a list for each word in the dictionary.  If you need to add pairs to a word frequently then a list is probably what you want, but if the lists of pairs are actually static, you'll want to you tuple instead.